# Como implementar uma exceção usando "IF AND ELSE" em uma consulta Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Eu tenho uma consulta que lista todos os bancos de dados, tabelas, rodovia, e datas. só que na consulta ele me retorna um erro na conclusão pq dentro do campo a onde estão armazenados todas as tabelas, há tabelas que não tem uma específica coluna. Estou querendo criar uma exceção para que se não tiver essa tal coluna dentro de uma 'x' tabela, que ele roda sem retornar um erro na conclusão da consulta.

> PS* O RESULTADO DA CONSULTA APARECE NORMALMENTE, PORÉM ELE VEM COM
>   "Consulta concluída com erros".Eu estou precisando por que depois eu vou ter que automatizar a consulta se não fosse a automatização que estou pensando em faze, eu poderia deixar bem assim,pq o resultado aparece normalmente para mim.

NO CASO A MINHA CONSULTA É ESSA:

```
DECLARE @Resultado TABLE
(
 Tabelas nvarchar(max),
 data_sincronizacao date,
 rodovia nvarchar(max),
 elemento nvarchar(max),
 n_foto int

)

 /*DECLARANDO VARIAVEIS PARA MINHA PROCEDURE */
DECLARE @Table_cursor CURSOR 
DECLARE @rodovia nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @elemento nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @database_name  nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @sql_insert nvarchar(MAX)

 /*CHAMANDO MEU CURSOR,APONTADANDO ELE PERCORER A TABELA DE REFERENCIA A ONDE ESTÁ ARMAZENADO OS BANCOS E AS TEBALES COM TERMINO "ATTACH" */
SET @Table_cursor = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT distinct Banco, Tabela, Rodovia, Elemento from Dados.dbo.Referencia
 /*LIMPANDO A TABELA "CONSULTA" PARA EVITAR DUPLICAÇÃO */
DELETE FROM Dados.dbo.Consulta


 /*ABRINDO O CURSOR PARA PERCORER TODOS OS DADOS DA TABELA REFERENCIA TRAZENDO DADOS DAS RESPECTIVAS COLUNAS */
OPEN @Table_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @Table_cursor INTO @database_name, @table_name, @rodovia, @elemento
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
    --PRINT 'Inserindo dados do banco ' + @database_name + ' e tabela ' + @table_name

    SET @sql_insert = CONCAT('INSERT INTO Consulta (Banco, Tabela, Rodovia, Elemento, n_foto, data_sincronizacao) SELECT ''', @database_name, ''', ''', @table_name, ''', ''', @rodovia, ''', ''', @elemento, ''', count(*) as n_foto, FORMAT (GDB_FROM_DATE, ''dd-MM-yyyy'') FROM ', @database_name, '.dbo.' + @table_name, ' GROUP BY FORMAT(GDB_FROM_DATE, ''dd-MM-yyyy'');')    

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_insert
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Table_cursor INTO @database_name, @table_name, @rodovia, @elemento
END
CLOSE @Table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE @Table_cursor;
```